# Disable inspection in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8, flake8

There are several articles explaining how to disable inspection in PyCharm by clicking my way around. I do not like that because:

- It does not work for me
- I have no idea what PyCharm is doing
- I want to disable PEP8 checking in certain cases, and not be bound to PyCharm

In `flake8` [I can ignore errors](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html?highlight=noqa#in-line-ignoring-errors) with `# noqa`, but PyCharm does not seem to respect that consistently.

How can I tell (in code) PyCharm to ignore errors in a specific line of code?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot with the warnings which you'd like to ignore?

Comment: This question should be asked more precisely: Does it have to be a solution that works in both Pycharm and other IDEs or will you be happy with a solution that only works in Pycharm. As @Sraw mentioned, you can use #noinspect but that will not work in other IDEs

Answer (score 3):

If you click `alt+enter` on the errors, you can see some choices.

For example, `Suppress for class`, `Suppress for function`, `Suppress for statement`.

You can choose one of them to suppress specific inspection or totally disable inspection for a given scope.

And also you can use `# noinspection xxx` to suppress inspection (The same as above).

For example, to suppress `PyBroadException`, you can use `# noinspection PyBroadException`. To totally disable inspection, you can use `# noinspection All`.

Comment: Thanks! Is that PyCharm specific then? What if other colleagues are using other tools? Is there an online list of error codes?

Comment: It is an IntelliJ specific annotation. And there is a list: https://gist.github.com/pylover/7870c235867cf22817ac5b096defb768. For your `alt+enter`, I have no idea why...

Comment: The question was a bit ambiguous, but I think it was written the spirit of finding a solution that is generic so both pycharm and other IDEs respect it. As far as I know there is no such possibility.

Comment: @Cerno I somehow don't understand you as the question title is exactly `in Pycharm`.

Comment: @Sraw My understanding of the posting guidelines at SO is that questions must be asked precisely. This question is asked in a way that indicates it is about suppressing inspection, and there is a mechanism for it, as you wrote. But at the same time OP asks about a way that is Pycharm-independent, and your answer does not fit that aspect, that's why I downvoted. But since the question is not well-formulated, it's hard to guess what the OP actually wants. Maybe you can add the information that there is no IDE-independent way of doing this (to my knowledge at least).

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 2020.1 and later recognize `# noqa` style suppressions!
https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2020/02/pycharm-2020-1-eap-4/