# PyCharm: how to disable Missing docstring inspection locally

Tags: python, pycharm, static-analysis, pylint, code-inspection

#### Question

I have a method in a Python class that I use `functools.wraps` to assign a docstring.  Here is the exact code I use:

`facade.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Facade."""


from functools import wraps

import back_end


@wraps(back_end.some_method)
def renamed_method(str_to_print):  # noinspection PyMissingOrEmptyDocstring
    back_end.some_method(str_to_print)
```

`back_end.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


"""Back End."""


def some_method(some_str: str) -> None:
    """Prints out a string.

    Args:
        some_str: A string to print

    """
    print(some_str)
```

PyCharm inspection warns `Missing docstring` on the method `renamed_method`.  This is what it looks like on my end:

[image: What I Can See]

I added `# pylint: disable=C0111` to the same line, and it does not make the warning go away.

**How can I make this warning go away?**  I do not want to uncheck the inspection globally.

---

#### What I Have Tried

FYI, I use `PyCharm CE 2018.3.7`.  I also just updated to `PyCharm CE 2019.2.2` and got the same results.  I use the default settings, only things I have changed are using Google docstring format and checking all inspection options for Python.

**#1: Lightbulb --> Suppression Option**

I looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51148355/11163122

Also documented on PyCharm's website [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppressing-comments).

And I don't get the suppression options it promises.

[image: Pressing on light bulb]

**#2: noinspection comment**

I also tried: `# noinspection PyMissingOrEmptyDocstring` (full list [here](https://gist.github.com/pylover/7870c235867cf22817ac5b096defb768)).  Here is the full attempt:

```
@wraps(back_end.some_method)
def renamed_method(str_to_print):  # noinspection PyMissingOrEmptyDocstring
    back_end.some_method(str_to_print)
```

And an image of what I am seeing:

[image: noinspection output]

---

#### Aside

Why do I use the `functools.wraps` decorator?  See [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm allows you to suppress (instead of disable) the inspection.

You can click the lightbulb and select 'suppress for this class' or add this manually:

```
# noinspection PyMissingOrEmptyDocstring
```

More here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections

Specific to the example as given, this won't work:

```
@wraps(back_end.some_method)
def renamed_method(str_to_print):  # noinspection PyMissingOrEmptyDocstring
    back_end.some_method(str_to_print)
```

But this will:

```
# noinspection PyMissingOrEmptyDocstring
@wraps(back_end.some_method)
def renamed_method(str_to_print):
    back_end.some_method(str_to_print)
```

Comment: I just updated the question @Grismar.  I found two things: 1. adding the `noinspection` comment did not work (see updated question).  2. the light bulb did not contain that option for me.  Is there some way the inspection should be refreshing that it's not?

Comment: Can you please share more of your code, or share some code that constitutes a complete example that shows the behaviour you describe in your setup? I can tell you "it shows the option just fine on my end", but that's not very helpful, however without knowing under what conditions you have this problem, it will be impossible to help.

Comment: Okay @Grismar.  I believe you.  I wonder, do you have PyCharm Pro?  I made a new PyCharm project, made test code, and placed it all here.  Do you have any other ideas?  I completely updated the question with new code/images.

Comment: Thanks for updating the example, I tried it out, had the same problem and fixed it by moving the `noinspection` to just before the declaration, see example as updated. By the way, I do have Pro, but Community and Pro are nearly identical and I was able to confirm on a colleague's Community edition that the same applies.

Comment: thank you very much for your repeated help!  That did the trick :) . People like you are what make Stack Overflow great!

Comment: Pay it forward and help someone with a question you know the answer to - you're welcome. :)